# Tcl scripting using grep,sed

Tags: sed, grep

I have to find a particular string first, then i need to pick up a value in that string, which is changing aftrr every run. How can i do this.

```
Stage pro begin_time { size is 54mb and 3 sec }
Stage pro1 begin_time  {.....}
```

I have very big file. I have to specifically look for `begin_time` string first then look for its value and store it somewhere.  How can i do this.
I have tried it using `grep` but i don't know how to store value of 3 here. Similarly i have many cases here, how can i handle this situation

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you are trying to do but the right solution will not involve grep or sed or a shell loop (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)). [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and include a few lines of concise, testable, sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat aaa
Stage pro begin_time { size is 54mb and 3 sec }
Stage pro1 begin_time  {.....}


cat aaa  |awk '$3=="begin_time" {print $9}' |grep .
3
```

if you wish to store it :

```
var=$(cat aaa  |awk '$3=="begin_time" {print $9}' |grep .)
echo $var
3
```

If you wish to map pro with 3 then,

```
cat aaa   | awk '$3=="begin_time" {print $2,$9}' |grep .
pro 3
```

Comment: UUOC (and grep): `cat aaa  |awk '$3=="begin_time" {print $9}' |grep .` will produce exactly the same output as the much simpler `awk '$3=="begin_time" {print $9}' aaa`.

Comment: ture, yours is smarter way! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I want to store it as value 3 with respect to pro, then some other value corresponding to pro1. Second, time mentioned here is a start time. I have same information for each of the stage pro,pro1 but with an end time. I have to extract end time as well. Then i have to caluculate net time elapsed, i.e. time between start time and end time

Comment: If you want to do that, then you need to put above code into while read loop.

Comment: @anmol Don't post comments as answers. Post them as comments and/or edit your question if you need to provide more information. Right now I don't even know if you're asking how to parse a tcl script with UNIX tools to modify that tcl script or how to call UNIX tools from tcl to help parse some other file or something else.